# Login screen does not continue

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, login

I updated from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. Now it does not leave the login screen.
When I type my password "correct" it reboots and returns to the same login screen.
What can do I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to get into a console screen login there. Then use `sudo chown` and `sudo chmod` on your home directory to regain access. Remember to use `-R` (so that all subfolders are set too).

Sample:

```
sudo chown -R myName:myName /home/myName/
sudo chmod -R 700 /home/myName/
```

Comment: Esse comando não funciona. Permanece do mesmo modo.

Comment: @LidiaPatrocinio English only please.